# Как из ссылки достать определенный кусочек из ссылки если у каждой по-разному заканчивается конец

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть ссылка `https://siteblalba/ru/attr/b45864c3` из нее нужно достать только b45864c3, но так как ссылок много у каждой этот "конец" начинается либо с буквы "**b**4864c3" либо с цифры "**4**bvs2ef", как правильно записать регулярное выражение, чтобы получить и тех и тех

Comment: `link = 'https://siteblalba/ru/attr/b45864c3'.split('/')[-1]`

Comment: Вас устраивает решение выше или всё таки надо регулярное выражение?

Comment: Нужна регулярное выражение, потому что в массиве только одну ссылку берет

Comment: Каком массиве? Пожалуйста, приведите [mre], в вопросе никаких массивов нет. Если вопрос действительно по регулярным выражениям, то поставьте метку [tag:регулярные-выражения], заодно описание её прочитайте

Comment: Вопрос в регулярном выражении, как получить только b45864c3 либо же 4bvs2ef

Comment: В общем, условие до сих пор непонятно. Почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/регулярные-выражения/info

Comment: Классическим регулярным выражением без извращений никак. Используйте сплит, как вам посоветовали сразу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import urllib

urllib.parse.urlparse("https://siteblalba/ru/attr/b45864c3").path.split("/")[-1]
```

ну или как хотите)

```
import re

re.search(r".*/ru/attr/(.*)", "https://siteblalba/ru/attr/b45864c3").groups()[0]
```

Comment: Почему регулярка такая? Она и `/ru/attr/` просто найдёт с пустой группой